# Why is my badge count different in different places?

Tags: support

Let me show you two screen shots:-

(From the top bar that also has the icons - 'Recent inbox messages' and 'Recent achievements')
[image]

(From the badges section of mu AU profile)

[image]

Clearly the badge count is different in different places(Shouldn't it be 33 [3 silver+30 bronze as it shows in the top bar] in the Badges section of my AU profile?). Why is this so?

Comment: I think it's because the first screenshot shows total amount while the second is about _different_ badge types.

Comment: yeah you are right @Danatela . I counted with Mitch's suggestion to view all my badges and I see 30 there. So its fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look under the listed badges, you will see a view more link,  when you click on it, you will see the total badge count.  See images below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: okay, but still it tells '29' badges. Is it because that 29 is the different types of badges rather the number of badges(as @Danatela says) ?

Comment: ah! yes it is. I counted and it was fine. So 29 is the number of different types of badges I have and 30 is the actual number of badges. got it. Thanks.