# My badge count is different in different places, and I don't like it

Tags: feature-request, badges

[This is related](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/10342/why-is-my-badge-count-different-in-different-places) (but not a duplicate as this is a feature request).

So here is my profile page:

[image]

The first red box totals 58.

The second red box says 41.

If I count the number of badges I get 58. If I count the number of **different** badges, I get 41.

Please, please could these numbers be the same? Or change the second box to say 41 different badges, like this:

[image]

Sorry for the lack of freehand circles and unicorns.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation for 1st case:**

It displays Total badges **with considering** how many times it is awarded. Ex: If one badge is awarded 5 times (i.e. Reviewer x5) than it will be counted as **5** at Main profile display (may be because of displaying total awarded in purpose of **[flair](https://askubuntu.com/users/flair/186134.png)**)  .

**Explanation for 2nd case:**

It displays Total badges **without considering** how many times it is awarded. Ex: If one badge is awarded 5 times (i.e. Nice Answer x6) than it will be counted as **1** at **users badges tab.**

Comment: The OP knows this, he mentions it in the question.